# Check if my auto.arima model is good

Tags: r, time-series, self-study, arima, model-evaluation

I am a self learner, and even I am new to R, I  have some data and I am trying to do time series analysis in R.

I first tried to do an  auto.arima  fit to the data.
I would liek to check if the obained arima model is  good enough or not.
I did  not check the stationarity of my data before doing the fit.

As I read, to check the arima model, you can keep some data points and  try to forecast them using the obtaiend ARIMA model. Or you can check the residuals.
In both cases I am mnot sure how to do this in R. Even I am not sure if this si the right way to go with time series  analysis.

I would be very thankful if any can help me, provinding me some specific references in this context.

Answer (score -2):

https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf presents the approach to analyzing univariate time series. It is an iterative , self-checking process that is similar to peeeling an onion back in order to get to a guassian process . It is the process of separating signal and noise .